# How to auto-size height of text block to image next to it HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm currently learning HTML and wanted to get my page to follow this format
[HTML Web Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8G8h.png)

So far I was able to get the image to the correct alignment and set my width of my images to 50%.
I want to have the text size next to it to match the height of the images, I saw other post that said to set the height of the text to the images height __px but I would like my height to be dynamic because depending on the window size my image height also changes how would I go about doing this on my css file.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `vw` when setting the height in that way when screen is resize. the height of your textbox is also resize.

Here's an example. Just adjust the value of your `height` in textbox that match the image height.

```css
.text_center {text-align:center;}
.image,.text {width:33%;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;position:relative;}
.image img {width:100%;max-width:100%;}
.text {border:1px solid #000;height:20vw;padding:20px;}
```

```html
<div class="text_center">
<div class="image">
<img src="https://cc.sj-cdn.net/instructor/z6375m3nz68l-juvare/courses/6oytt1p0oah5/promo-image.1588082521.jpg">
</div>
<div class="text">
Sample Text
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As i don't have comment option, i am adding as an answer.

1. You can add same class as image and set the height property.
2. You can use table also. Add a table and put all your elements in it. Set the properties.

Comment: dont mis-use an anwser to comment! Not having the priveledge earned for commenting does not mean you can mis-use the anwser option for it. Besides that, tables should only be used for displaying data. For styling purpose you shouldnt use tables as it is not only ancient and outdated but a bad use. For that you have css-grid.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is to use the css-grid. You just do a 2 column layout with 2 equal columns. The height within a row will always be the same. Full responsiveness, lowest coding efford.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg">
<div>Text</div>
<div>Text</div>
<img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg">
```